# Using variable in PHP array string

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wondered if you would help with the below.

I have a string which selects products from my WP woocommerce site which have certain taxonomies attached to them. What I want is to include a variable in my array.

What I have at the minute is this, which works great:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_garment',
            'field' => 'tag_ID',
            'terms' => '59'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_audience',
            'field' => 'tag_ID',
            'terms' => '39'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);


$args = $args;

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
} { 
    $image = print_r(get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'));
}

$image = $image[0];     

$image =  apply_filters( 'woocommerce_placeholder_img_src',$image[0] );
```

But instead of me specifying the categories "39" and "59" I want to insert variables, $category1 and $category2.

So i've tried this but it doesn't appear to work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_garment',
            'field' => 'tag_ID',
            'terms' => $category1
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_audience',
            'field' => 'tag_ID',
            'terms' => $category2
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);


$args = $args;

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
} { 

    $image = print_r(get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'));
}
$image = $image[0];     

$image =  apply_filters( 'woocommerce_placeholder_img_src',$image[0] );
```

I've tried adding extra $ at the beggining of the variable ($$category1), also adding extra bracket ${$category1} but i can't seem to figure it out.

Please help!

Cheers
Chris

Comment: That should work, problem must be somewhere else. Where are `$category1` and `$category2` defined?

Comment: what are $category1 and $category2 defined with?

Comment: I'm not sure to get why there are curly braces after the while loop

Comment: I think you might be right Karlingen, my $category1 is defined by: $category1 = $category->term_id; but i set it to $category1 = 59; it works. Any ideas to fix this? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

$category 1 and $category 2 must be an array, so first you need to get the terms associated to the taxonomy

```
$category1 = array('term1', 'term2');
```

or term ids:

```
$category1 = array(1,2,3);
```

use the function get_terms( $taxonomies, $args ), to obtain an array of terms